# Скорость выполнения

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

работаю с sqlalchemy, меня не устраивает скорость select из базы, индексы все расставлены. Результат скорости без установления соединения, т.к. скрипт висит в загрузке. Производительность сервер высокая, нагрузка на него 10% max. Выбор идет из одной таблице в таблице 142143 записей.

```
 def instantiate(p):
    global engine
    engine =   sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://radius_dhcp:eerer@10.0.3.252:3306/fff', pool_recycle=25200, pool_size=100, max_overflow=10)

def conndb():
    return engine.connect()

def _handleDHCPDiscover(chaddr,venid,xid,rip,sid,cip,vlan,port,switch,t):
    tstart = datetime.now()
    dbHandle = conndb()
    res = dbHandle.execute(select_mac.format(switch,chaddr)).fetchall()
    tend = datetime.now()
    print tend - tstart
    speed=0:00:00.000600
```

Можно как-то еще увеличь быстродействие запроса именно скорости?

Comment: в таблице больше 100к записей? и оно Вам все нужно одновременно? Там видимо много данных. Пока все эти данные утащатся, пока в памяти разместятся.

Comment: Выхода из ситуации нет?

      
           SELECT  iz.name sw,inet_ntoa(4294967295 & izd.net) net,
        inet_ntoa(4294967295 & izd.mask) mask, inet_ntoa(4294967295 & izd.gateway) gw,
        inet_ntoa(4294967295 & ip) ip
  FROM ip_zones iz,ip_zones_detail izd,ip_groups ipg
  WHERE iz.id=izd.ip_zone_id and iz.name='{0}' and ipg.mac='{1}' and ipg.is_deleted=0;


Мой запрос в базу

Comment: почему Вы не отвечаете на вопрос? Может быть не нужно всё в память загружать? Или, если эти данные более-менее постоянные, то можно хранить себе в текстовом/бинарном файле (такой себе кеш).

Comment: понял смысл.

Comment: Смыл понятен, можно переделать, спасибо!

Comment: Делаю элементарный запрос 

     dbHandle.execute("select 1;")

Результат: 0:00:00.000413

Есть еще мысли?

Comment: Во-первых не из одной таблицы: "FROM ip_zones iz,ip_zones_detail izd,ip_groups ipg". Во-вторых, индексы на поля name и mac есть? Там значения более-менее уникальные?

Comment: > 0:00:00.000413
Нормальный результат :/